# How to construct a new positie matrix for given matrixt

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

For Given Matrix Q , I need help in construting new matrix P in order to QP will be positive definite. The Details and examples are as follows:

Let $Q=\begin{pmatrix}
         rI & A^\mathrm{T} \\
         0 & sI \\
       \end{pmatrix}$,
       $P=\begin{pmatrix}
     B & C \\
     D & E \\
   \end{pmatrix}$,
So that $QP$ is positive definite. Please give as more as 
possible forms of matrix $P$ and the conditions for positive definiteness of $QP$.
($r,s \in R$ are constants, $I$ is identity matrix.)

For example,
\begin{eqnarray*}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
  P_1 &=& \begin{pmatrix}
     I & \frac{1}{r}A^\mathrm{T} \\
     0 & I \\
   \end{pmatrix}, ( rs \geq \|A^TA\| ), \\
  P_2  &=& \begin{pmatrix}
     I & 0 \\
     \frac{-1}{s}A & I \\
   \end{pmatrix} ,(rs \geq \|A^TA\|), \\
  P_3 &=& (1-\tau)P_1 + \tau P_2,( rs \geq \frac{3}{4}\|A^TA\|, \tau \in [0,1]), \\
  P_4 &=& \begin{pmatrix}
     I & \frac{1}{2r}A^\mathrm{T} \\
     \frac{-1}{2s}A & I-\frac{AA^T}{2rs} \\
   \end{pmatrix}, ( rs \geq \frac{1}{4}\|A^TA\| ).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I don't know how you done those $QP_i$ is not symmetric. And giving all $P$ / $QP\ge 0$ is ' impossible'.

Comment: Sorry it do not need to symmetric, only positive definite.

Comment: give as more as possible forms of matrix $P$, not to be all P.

Comment: Not trivial to give